# Q-function in Q-Learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, supervised-learning, pattern-recognition, semi-supervised-learning

I ran into solved old-exam question as follows:
[image]

My notes tell me that option b is correct but I think option d is correct. is there any idea why (b) is correct?

Answer (score 1):

b) is not correct. By the standard definition, neither is d, however d is the closest.

A more correct definition would go something along the lines of "The expected total future *discounted* reward starting in a state $s$, executing an action $a$ and thereafter following a specified policy $\pi$."

Comment: Right, so the issue here is that you're faced with a slightly wishy-washy question that's asking how well you learned the definitions given to you in the course and then fit these to vague multiple choice answers. Indeed the Q-learning algorithm is typically aiming to learn the Q-function for an optimal policy, and that's likely what the 'successful training' part refers to. However, I'd have no qualms about writing "Given a policy $\pi$, we will use Q-learning to estimate the Q-function associated with $\pi$" in a research paper.

Comment: At the end of the day the important part is being consistent with the definitions you're working with, and explicitly state what you are referring to. Anyway, good luck with your exam!

Comment: would you please add a reference for your sentence that your wrote in "the expected total future discounted...." ?

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph A formal definition would involve the corresponding mathematical expression, as in section 1.3 of Szepesvari's book. Since the question is in terms of a wordy 'definition',  I provided the reserved claim of 'a more correct definition', rather than the definition itself.

Comment: Thanks but here there is no part 1.3   

https://sites.ualberta.ca/~szepesva/papers/RLAlgsInMDPs.pdf